# How to test Assert for base class exception implementation using Microsoft Unit testing framework?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-unit-testing

Here is specific case. I want to test this `Assert.ThrowsException<DbException>(() => { MyMethod(0, 100); });`

The problem is that exception thrown is `SqlException`. Why do I want to test base exception? Because I want a unified test for any of my 3 DB providers. The exception sometimes is `OracleException` or `MySqlException`. All 3 providers exceptions derive from `DbException`

Is there a way to test it nicely, using the Microsoft Unit Test framework?

Comment: Unless it's recently changed and you're using an older version, it's still not possible. It will check for the specific type of the exception; not its base type. Maybe the "best" way to deal with that is to implement your own `MyDbException` in your access layer, catch it as `SqlException` and throw and assert it as `MyDbException`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the leads, one from @StephanAdler

Considering limitations of given testing framework my sensible solution was this

```cs
Exception retEx = null;

try
{
    MyMethod(0, 100);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    retEx = ex;
}

Assert.IsNotNull(retEx);
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(retEx, typeof(DbException));
```

`Assert.IsInstanceOfType` works perfectly with the base type

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [Assert.ThrowsException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.throwsexception?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) this is expected. However, if you're able to use [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/), this is in fact very easy to achieve.

```cs
Action action = () => MyMethod(0, 100);
action.Should().Throw<DbException>(); // add some more checks

// this would mimic the behavior of Assert.ThrowsException, which should fail.
action.Should().ThrowExactly<DbException>();
```

See also the tips on improving assertions under [Tips/Exceptions](https://fluentassertions.com/tips/#exceptions).

The **alternative** would be to use regular `try...catch` like in the example below. You need to make sure that you capture all the code path' and don't accidentally succeed:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Catching a base exception class just by using <see cref="Assert"/>.
    /// Do not use <see cref="ExpectedExceptionAttribute"/>, since it doesn't
    /// provide any type of validation.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void CatchAderivedExceptionTheAssertWay()
    {
        try
        {
            // A test method that throws an exception.
            Action action = () => throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
            action();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            // This will catch any exception derived from ArgumentException.
            // Do some validation to ensure the right thing is caught,
            // like checking the parameter name.
            if (!e.ParamName.Equals("param1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                Assert.Fail("Reason why the validation failed.");
            }

            // Otherwise jump out of the test.
            return;
        }

        Assert.Fail("Make sure the test fails, in case the code inside try doesn't throw at all.");
    }
```

For completeness sake, there's also the [ExpectedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) attribute that can be added to a `[TestMethod]`. Due to the lack of validation options I would not recommend using it.

I'll add this question to my list of interview questions. Such a nice example.

Comment: Cool. I don't want to start including additional libraries in this case because it is some legacy code. But definitely worth researching for the new projects. Basically, your answer is - not possible.